# Get Selected Value for drop down list

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have filled my drop down list on client side using jQuery script.

However, on post back the selected values of drop down list does NOT get maintained.

How can i set the selected value to drop down list on server side Or is it possible on client side...

I am creating my drop down list dynamically and my drop down list is a server side control.

Comment: What server side language are you using? (this isn't a JS question)

Comment: I am using vb.net language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side:

set the value with `$("#the_select").val(the_value);`

get the value with `$("#the_select").val();`

Comment: yes, but how can retrieve those values. because i have multiple drop down lists and my selected index changed event is on client side...

Comment: When the client submit the POST request to the server make sure to include the selected value for each select. The server will then be able to build the page and set the selection as it was on the client (on the server you have access to all the values of the selects otherwise you couldn't build the page originally...)

Comment: I do not have a single value of the Select on the server side. When i checked drop down list items on page post back it doesn't contain any value. When i have set the Selected Value using request.form, value does not get set.